# Combining data in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query that gives me this data:

```
| id |     job    | firstName | lastName |
+----+------------+-----------+----------+
| 1  | Programmer |   NULL    |   NULL   |
| 2  |    NULL    |   Tom     |   Tucker |
```

But I need the table to look like this:

```
| id |    job     | firstName | lastName |
+----+------------+-----------+----------+
| 1  | Programmer |   Tom     |  Tucker  |
```

I need for it to display like this, not change the data in the database.

Comment: I think your question is a bit unclear. If the first group is something you *queried* for, I would edit your question to show a little more from the original table, and your sample final results so that it is easier to recreate the issue. Also, if you do that and include the original query you wrote to get that first result set, it might be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `aggregate` functions. Try this,

```
select min(Id) as Id,max(job) as Job,max(FNAME) as FNAME,max(LName) as LNAME
from yourtable
```